# railsで全てのアカウントに自動投稿を一斉に行わせたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby on railsで
モデルに対して定時的な処理(rakeタスク）を書いているのですが、
一斉に実行される処理の仕方がわからず困っています。

例えば、Accountモデルにはアカウント（レコード）が101件あり、
それぞれのアカウントには数量残高が記録されています。
例外（回収役となる1件アカウント）を除き、
それぞれのアカウントの残高から１％の数量を算出して回収し、
回収した数量とアカウントidを１つのレコード（取引記録）として、計100件のレコードを
AccountTransaction（取引記録）モデルに記録（自動投稿）したいと思っています。

Accountモデル
・id（主キー）
・balance（残高数量）

AccountTransactionモデルには、
・id(主キー）
・amount(取引数量）
・withdrawal_account_id（支払側の口座id)
・deposit_account_id（回収役で受取側の口座id）

この場合、どのような実装をすれば実現できるのか教えて頂ければ幸いです。
AccountTransaction側のモデルファイル

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :withdrawal_account_transaction, class_name: 'AccountTransaction', :foreign_key => 'withdrawal_account_id'
  has_many :deposit_account_transaction, class_name: 'AccountTransaction', :foreign_key => 'deposit_account_id'

end
```

AccountTransaction側のモデルファイル

```
class AccountTransaction < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :withdrawal, class_name: 'Account', :foreign_key => 'withdrawal_account_id'
   belongs_to :deposit, class_name: 'Account', :foreign_key => 'deposit_account_id'
end
```

lib/tasksのrakeファイル。

```
namespace :currency_cycle do
  desc "全アカウント残高から一斉回収"
  task :cycle => :environment do

    begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction{
            #取引アカウントにレコードを一括作成(実験中)
            AccountTransaction.where.not(id: 19).create(
                deposit_account_id: 19,#回収役の口座id、固定なので直接idを記入している
                withdrawal_account_id: ?????????????",
                amount: ???????????
                )
        }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: よく似た質問 https://teratail.com/questions/106402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

teratail の方の投稿も見ましたが、「一斉」や「一括」という単語でどのような操作を
イメージしているのかが解りません。
全体を一つの transaction にしておけば、各 Account について順次処理していくだけで
良いのではないでしょうか。

試していないのでイメージですが、

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # 回収側の取得
  deposit_account = Account.find(19)
  # 各支払い側について
  Account.order(:id).each do |account|
    # account が回収側なら何もしない
    next if account.id == deposit_account.id
    # 支払額計算 (1%)
    amount = account.balance / 100
    # この支払いについて AccountTransaction のレコードを作成
    AccountTransaction.create!(
      withdrawal_account_id: account.id,
      deposit_account_id: deposit_account.id,
      amount: amount)
    # 残高を減額
    account.balance -= amount
    account.save!
  end
end
```

という感じです。

Comment: 「一斉」「一括」は、当初はupdate_allみたいなものをイメージしていていました。

Comment: 「大量のレコードを扱う一括的な処理はupdate_allみたくワンアクションで一気にやらなければならない」みたいな思い込みをしていました。ですが、よくよく考えるとやりたいことは「それぞれのアカウントが新しいレコード（投稿）を自動的に作成すること」なので、たしかにeachメソッドで処理した方が適切ですね。